# Where a result ends in specific characters, append characters to the end of a result

Tags: mysql, string, append

The following query gives the following result.

I am trying to edit the query to append "HR" to results where the result end in "F1", like the second entry.

Query:

```
select media.med_housenumber
from media
join mediainventoryrevision mir on mir.meir_med_id = media.med_id
join mediainventorycut mic on mic.mic_meir_id = mir.meir_id
join packageelement on packageelement.pke_mic_id = mic.mic_id
join version on version.ver_id = packageelement.pke_ver_id
where ver_packagehouse = 'P477914-005'
```

Result:

```
1219835HR
1189966F1
1237168HR
```

Results should be:

```
1219835HR
1189966F1HR
1237168HR
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `IF` or `CASE` expression to test the end of the value and append the desired string when the test succeeds.

```
SELECT IF(RIGHT(media.med_housenumber, 2) = 'F1',
          CONCAT(media.med_housenumber, 'HR'),
          media.med_housenumber) AS med_housenumber
FROM ...
```